# Fatal error on Amazon AWS SDK StreamWrapper PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install Amazon AWS SDK StreamWrapper on cPanel.

I have this code in my `s3_Upload.php` file:

```
<?php         
require 'aws/aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$s3Client= S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => "<key>",
    'secret' => "<secret_key>"
));

$s3Client->registerStreamWrapper();

$s3Bucket = '<bucket_name>';

$s3Path = 's3://'.$s3Bucket;

if (file_exists($s3Path.'/<folder>/clip.mp4')) {
    echo 'Clip exists!';
} else {
    echo 'Clip doesnt exists!';
}
?>
```

and I have both the `aws.phar` file and extracted version of `aws-sdk-php-master.zip`.

**Issue**: 
Whenever I try to go to `www.example.com/s3_Upload.php` it writes this **error**:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /home/<user>/public_html/aws/aws.phar on line 17
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @JeremyLindblom, **5.4.31**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your PHP environment is missing PHP/PECL's [Phar class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phar.php). This is odd, because, according to the [Phar Installation page](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php), "The Phar extension is built into PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0.".

So either you need to make sure the Phar extension is installed, or you need to use the `aws.zip`.

Note: The `aws.zip` is not the same as the `aws-sdk-php-master.zip` you've mentioned. I assume what you have is just a download of the SDK source from GitHub. That zip file would not contain any of the SDKs dependencies like `aws.phar` and `aws.zip` do. To use the official `aws.zip`, please see [Installing from the Zip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html#installing-via-zip) from the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide.

Comment: Great, feel free to ping @awsforphp on Twitter if you need help in the future. I try to watch SO, but I sometimes miss things. The [SDK's README](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) has links to other ways you can contact us too (forum, blog, issue tracker, etc.).

Comment: I can't find a source on how to, create a folder and then put files in it. Any links?

Comment: Try looking through these 2 pages in the user guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html.